# compute gram matrix in R

Tags: r

I need some help to compute a nXn gram matrix K for a given kernel. Here is my R code that generates simulated data. I could be any positive definite matrix. Taking diagonal matrix for simplicity.

```
     set.seed(3)
     n=20
     x=runif(n)
     y=rnorm(n)
    df<-cbind(x,y)

  I=diag(2)

kernel<-function(x,y) {
    t(x)%*%I%*%y
     }
   # for example 
#K[1,1]
    t(df[1,])%*%I%*%df[1,]
          [,1]
    [1,] 0.5829376
#K[1,2]
t(df[1,])%*%I%*%df[2,]
          [,1]
[1,] 0.978207
```

Comment: If you have a linear kernel like in your example just do `t(df) %*% I %*% df` ?

Comment: I get an error as follows

Comment: df<-as.matrix(df)
     t(df)%*%I%*%df
    Error in t(df) %*% I : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Comment: Then you are not using the code above. If you create `df` like in your question `t(df)` works without problems. Just take care of the dimensionalities of the involved matrices, i.e. do `df%*%I%*%t(df)` instead of `t(df)%*%I%*%df`.

Answer (score 1):

Example in the case of a linear regression model for a database call `data` with a response `Y` and predictors `X1` and `X2`:

```
#The regression model
model=lm(Y~X1+X2, data)

#Estimating residuals
r=model$res

#Estimating hat values
h=hatvalues(model)

#Computing Gramm matrix
d=r/(1-h)

#Estimating Gramm determinant (which summarizes the information in the Gramm matrix)
press=t(d)%*%d
round(press,2)
```

I hope, despite the delay, this may be useful for someone. Best regards.